# If you're using a UIStoryboard, will UIViewController call awakeFromNib?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

simple question,

If you're using a UIStoryboard, will UIViewController call awakeFromNib?

If not, what is the alternative method being called that we should use?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `awakeFromNib` is being called.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html):

> Initializing a View Controller Loaded from a Storyboard When you
>   create a view controller in a storyboard, the attributes you configure
>   in Interface Builder are stored in an archive. Later, when the view
>   controller is instantiated, this archive is loaded into memory and
>   processed. The result is a set of objects whose attributes match those
>   you set in Interface Builder. Here’s how that archive is loaded:
>
> If your view controller implements an initWithCoder: method, that
>   method is called to process the information in the archive. If your
>   view controller does not implement an initWithCoder: method, your view
>   controller’s init method is called instead.
>
> After the objects in the archive are loaded, iOS calls the awakeFromNib method on any objects
>   that implement such a method. You use this method to perform any
>   configuration steps that require other objects to already be
>   instantiated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `awakeFromNib` will be called when using a `UIStoryboard`.

While a .storyboard file is a XML document, it will get converted to a set of traditional .nib files when you compile/package your app, so decoding those will be the same as in xib-based projects.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `awakeFromNib` will be called when using a UIStoryboard.